# Can someone help me understand this? (From the terms to an insurance policy)

Tags: translation, meaning

I am working through some terms to an insurance policy at the moment and I came across something that doesn't quite make sense to me. Under the terms for 個人賠償責任保険金 (Insurance Payment for Damages/Liability), there is a clause that continues: 保険期間中の次の偶然な事故により、他人の生命または身体を害したり、他人の物を壊したりして、法律上の損害賠償責任を負われた場合 which I understand more or less, my rough interpretation being "Insurance shall be paid in cases in which the buyer is held legally responsible for damages caused by any of the unforeseen accidents during the coverage period set forth below causing bodily harm or death to another person or damaging the property of another person."

What I don't quite follow is the next part, which says:
（1）本人の居住の用に供される住宅の所有、使用または管理に起因する偶然な事故

Looking at this sentence out of context I would imagine something like "Unforeseen accidents stemming from the possession, use, or management of a residence provided for the habitation of the insured", but this just does not make sense to me in context. The insurance is for people who have purchased a bicycle and covers them for liability in relation to accidents caused while on or riding the bicycle.

If someone could give me an interpretation that makes better sense, I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 「本人の居住の用に供される住宅の所有、使用または管理に起因する偶然な事故」

While this is only a noun phrase (relative clause), not a "sentence" as you call it, your translation of it is spot-on.

What has this got to do with a bicycle insurance?

Many bicycle insurance plans in Japan, including even the more inexpensive ones, just come with coverage for these types of non-bicycle-related accidents.  So, you should only be happy.

Mine covers the same thing as yours (in-house accidents) in addition to accidents like breaking things while shopping in stores and sport injuries.  And I sure do not need to go to those places by bicycle to get covered.

Comment: 同じ結論に達したところでした。 For example [this plan](http://www.yodobashi.com/ec/support/member/function/family/index.html) clearly states 「※補償対象となる事故は自転車事故に限りません」.